# JSF: strange iframe when using multipart/form-data and AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, multipartform-data

**UPD:** this error is caused by installing PrimeFaces 4.0.

I have a problem with multipart/form-data and AJAX in JSF 2.2.4 (Glassfish 4.0.0). When I type something, a strange iframe is shown with id JSFFrameId that contains AJAX's responce. Something like this:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" id="JSFFrameId" name="JSFFrameId">
    <partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[1204950170773864689:-3204770436768457110]]></update></changes></partial-response>
</iframe>
```

But the value is set. What's wrong? Is it a bug?
JSF form:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:outputText value="#{foo.string}" id="asd" />
    <h:inputText value="#{foo.string}">
        <f:ajax event="change" render="asd" />
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "foo")
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean {
    private String string;

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be this bug: [JSF jira](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2843)

Comment: OP mentioned he's using Mojarra 2.2.4.